# How to compute the combined probability of loss for 2 time series (consisting of historical stock prices)?

Tags: time-series, risk, probability, distribution, copula

May I please ask the community's support with the following problem?

I have 2 time series, with approximately 1000 observations each (same number of observations for both). They represent the daily closing prices for 2 stocks: asset A and asset B. Assuming we are currently at time t, I'm interested in computing (forecasting) the probability that, (at anytime) over the next 5 days (i.e. t+1, t+2, t+3, t+4, t+5), either stock A's or B's price will fall by at least $r_{loss}$%:

$$
Pr[P^{A}_{t+i}<P^{A}_{t}*(1-r_{loss})\ \textbf{or}\ P^{B}_{t+i}<P^{B}_{t}*(1-r_{loss})\ for\ some\ i\in\{1,2,3,4,5\}]=\ ?
$$

For added clarity:

- t = current time; I only have information (observations) up to
  and including time **t**
- $P^{A}, P^{B}$ = price of stock A, price of stock  B
- $r_{loss}$ = loss threshold, $r_{loss}\in[0,1]$. For example, $r_{loss}=0.03$ represents a $3\%$ loss.

Comment: Do you have a model for the stocks or do want to do something like [filtered historical simulation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Historical_simulation_(finance))?

Comment: @BobJansen thank you very much for your interest! I don't have a model. To be honest I would prefer to do something like filtered historical simulation. But if there's a suitable solution that requires a model I'm happy to give it a try

Comment: We need to know your end goal or at least more context of this question to be able to suggest suitable models.

Comment: @BobJansen My (ideal) end goal is to forecast if 2 assets are negatively correlated over the next 5 days (and also how strong their relationship is). But, I'm not sure how to forecast that, as I want to do it for 5 observations only. Therefore, I qualitatively selected pairs of assets that I know to usually be negatively correlated. Then I just try to forecast the probability of a loss, greater than a particular threshold, for that pair assuming that the negative relationship holds.

Comment: @BobJansen Sorry, not sure if I was clear in my previous comment. My goal is to forecast the co-movement of 2 assets for the next 5 days (using only daily OHLC prices). And, additionally, I'm want to forecast the probability of a  price drop beyond a given threshold (that can incur at any time: {t+1, t+2, t+3, t+4, t+5}) that any of the 2 assets can experience over the next 5 days. For the co-movement part I'm using a qualitative guess right now. Therefore, my question above: I'm looking for a method to forecast the price drop probability. Thanks for your interest once again!